# WebDav folders not accessabile on servers

Tags: windows-server-2003, sharepoint, webdav

We've got a SharePoint farm set up and can access it via WebDav in Explorer like so: \ourlocalSharepoint.  None of the servers are able to access the files in this manner, only client machines.  But all can get to the web url, http://ourlocalSharepoint.  I think the win2k3 image we are using to install has had some bits removed/turned off, but since I wasn't the one who did it, I don't know what was done to the win2k3 installer.  What bits/services need to be turned on so a windows box can access webdav folders?

Comment: It would be helpful to know or see the specific error message you are receiving when you browse the Sharepoint site and try to go to Explorer View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into services.msc and enable the WebClient service.

Answer (score 0):

Install the WebDav client on your server

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=17C36612-632E-4C04-9382-987622ED1D64&displaylang=en

Comment: Tried that.  Still no dice.  The issue is that it will not even find the web dav folders.

Comment: Did you disable protected mode?  Tools->Internet Options->Security.  Also add your site to the Intranet zone